# Sending Json string in a required format using SimpleJson

Tags: c#, json

Hi guys I am struggling a bit with this simpleJson lib and I could use a bit of assistance on how to send a json string in a required format.

For example I wanted to construct a json string like this:

```
    {
      "Type": "Token",
      "Denomination": 2.0,
      "count": 2
    }
```

But when I use simplejson.jsonclass to construct a json it is constructing all the values as  strings which is like this
`c# code : json["count"].AsInt=2` ;

```
{
  "Type": "string",
  "Denomination": "2.0",
  "count": "2"
}
```

Please tell me how can I construct a proper json with the values in a certain format cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the more code snippet, including how you are constructing the object (json in your example) and serializing this object.

or probably you want to use simpleJson in following way

```
    class JsonStructure
    {
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public Decimal Denomination { get; set; }
        public Decimal count { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var input = "{ \"Type\": \"Token\", \"Denomination\": 2.0, \"count\": 2 }";
        var json = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<JsonStructure>(input);
        json.count = 3;
        var output = SimpleJson.SerializeObject(json);
        if(output.Equals("{ \"Type\": \"Token\", \"Denomination\": 2.0, \"count\": 3 }"));
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: that is not what i am looking for as i said above i am constructing my own json and this is what i am doing in c# var test = new JSONClass();
  test["oops"]="testing";
  test["ooops"]="2.0";
  test ["oooops"].AsInt = 2;

Comment: The SimpleJson that you are using does not had support for your scenario. I believe you were calling test.ToString() to finally generate the json string. <br>

I have updated the SimpleJson Code to provide functionality you are looking for. I have just provided functionality to "ToString()". Let me know, If you are intending to use "Serialize()".

Find the updated Code [here http://codeshare.io/JNpKm](http://codeshare.io/JNpKm). You need to replace this code in SimpleJson.cs